# Mapquest providedLocation

Tags: javascript, google-maps, mapquest

I have a problem with Mapquest. Everything was working just fine until I noticed markers are not showing up on my maps. I didn't change any code, and the mapquest api documentation doesn't seem to have been updated.

Basically, I make a geocoding call and process the json response. I pass in data that is needed for the callback function to properly place markers on a google map.

```
function addMarker(street_address,city,state,company_name,ri){
        var safe_name = company_name.replace("&#39;","\'");
        safe_name = safe_name.replace("&", "%26");
        var new_index = ri + 1;

        var api_url = "http://open.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=MY_KEY&location=" + street_address + " " + city + ", " + state + "&name=" + safe_name + "&record_index=" + new_index + "&callback=renderGeocode";
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.src = api_url;
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }

    function renderGeocode(response) {
        var location = response.results[0].locations[0];
        var address = response.results[0].providedLocation.location;
        var lat = location.latLng.lat;
        var lng = location.latLng.lng;
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        var map_icon = iconBase + record_index + ".png";
        var name = response.results[0].providedLocation.name;
        var record_index = response.results[0].providedLocation.record_index;

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: latlng,
            icon: map_icon
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            window.location = "/yellow_pages/get-directions.aspx?address=" + address + "&co=" + name_for_marker + "&searchtext=<%=Server.UrlEncode(searchtext)%>&location=<%=location%>";
        })
    }
```

Before Mapquest made their changes,

```
var name = response.results[0].providedLocation.name;
        var record_index = response.results[0].providedLocation.record_index;
```

would both return the values I passed to mapquest. This is no longer the case? Has anyone had a similair issue? Like I said, the documentation on mapquest is either out of date, or I'm a big dummy.

Comment: Why is this tagged google-maps?

Comment: @geocodezip good question. I went ahead and tossed the mapquest garbage and went strictly with the google maps geocoder and all is well.

Comment: If you're still looking at the MapQuest geocoder - There have not been any recent changes to the open geocoder. Are you seeing any errors in the console or any indications of problems in the network tab? You can use the licensed data geocoder at www.mapquestapi.com which is much better.